# There is a way to link GLKit in an IOS4 app?

Tags: opengl-es, ios4, glkit

I build an application that uses GLKit in order to draw OpenGL stuff on the screen. I know that this is an iOS5 framework but, I was wondering if there is a way to link with glkit dylib by hand. I'll appreciate if I do not need to rebuild my code since GLKit is much more easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is non known way for the iPhone.

I tried the same for OS X 10.6 with a copy of the GLKit framework library from OS X 10.8 and as i already supposed they used features that where not available in OS X 10.6 an my application just quits. With 10.7 it worked since 10.8 is pretty close to the previous OS X.

You can try to copy the GLKit Framework from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework to the path of the iPhone 4 SDK folder.

The framework and header files should then be accessible in your older Xcode version which is probably in /Developer since you are using an old version of Xcode.

Comment: My example folder is for the iOS 6 SDK. If you have iOS 5.x SDK's installed you should use them instead. Its closer to version 4.

Comment: I solved this problem a long time ago by extracting all the headers from GLKit that are inline (like Matrix.h) and implementing by hand the functions I needed, such the texture loader functions.

But now, I think iOS4 is about to become depracated. I stoped with iOS development a while ago.

Comment: Thats true :) After answering i saw that the question is nearly a year old. Anyways i think that this could be useful for other frameworks too in the future.

Comment: Could you share your sources? I need it :)